# Como calcular o produto dos elementos de um array em C

Tags: c

Como faço para multiplicar valores de um vetor de inteiros um pelo outro em C. Tenho os valores dentro de um array por exemplo [1,2,3,4], quero multiplicar um pelo outro, resultando em 24.

Comment: Em C ou em Java? O que você já fez? Elabore mais sua pergunta.

Comment: É em C tinha colocado a tag errada já corrigi.

Answer (score 10):

É só utilizar um laço for para percorrer o array e multiplicar os elementos um de cada vez em um acumulador. O valor inicial do acumulador é 1 porque este é o elemento neutro da multiplicação.

```c
int array[] = {1,2,3,4};
int produto = 1, i;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    produto *= array[i];
}
```

Comment: Sim estou usando o laço , ok, precisa deste elemento neutro valeu a força.

Comment: Ou pode inicializar o produto com o primeiro valor do array e comecar a iterar o array a partir da posicao 1

Comment: @JoaoRaposo mas a solução do Victor é a mais didática, o que me parece apropriado pelo nível da pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas e tb achei a resposta do victor mais didática.

Comment: @fotanus terei de concordar consigo, a minha sugestao reflete o que acontece no dia a dia mas nao e' dida'tica de todo.

Answer (score 0):

Para multiplicar e somar os elementos de um array é basicamente fazer uma sucessão de termos.

Temos o seguinte:
    ////////////////

```
int *vector = {1,2,3,4};
int i, total = 0;
/*Realizar a primeira iteracao da sucessao*/
total = vetor[0];
/*Fazer um ciclo a começar em i=1*/
for(i=1; i<4; i++){
   total = total * vetor[i];
}
printf("Total: %d", total);
```

Comment: errado, você está somando o valor das multiplicações.

Answer (score 0):

Faça um laço de repetição percorrendo o array inteiro, crie uma variavel do tipo inteiro para armazenar o resultado e a multiplique pelo valor que está no indice do array.....

```
int main(){
    int vetor[4] = {1,2,3,4};
    int total = vetor[0];
    total = vetor[0];
        for(int i=1; i<4; i++){
            total = total * vetor[i];
        }
    printf("%d", total);
}
```

Comment: errado, você está somando o valor das multiplicações.

Comment: Estava errada a inicialização da variavel total, que estava iniciando em zero, porém o laço de repetição está correto.

Comment: Agora ela está correta, porém quando eu havia visualizado a mesma estava atribuindo o resultado + o valor já estava na variável total (assim como na resposta do @urb ).

Comment: '~' Não tinha usado IDE, mas mesmo assim obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

```
int mmc = 1;
for (int m = 0; m < divisor.Count; m++)
{
     mmc = mmc *divisor[m];
}
```

Inicie a variável com `1`, assim ela multiplicará por ela mesmo e na próxima poderá multiplicar, se iniciar com zero ele nunca será diferente de zero.

Fiz desse jeito e deu certo.